# Take recommendation from 3 different tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 3 different recommendation model that gives me the output in three different tables.

**Recommendation 1 :** In a ideal situation, I want to take top 2 recommendation per user from this table ordered by ProductRecommendation ascending.

[image]

**Recommendation 2 :** In a ideal situation, I want to take top 3 recommendation per user from this table based on top score.

[image]

**Recommendation 3 :** In a ideal situation, take remaining recommendation from this table to add up to 5 recommendation per user

[image]

In the end, I want to see a final output which is a merge of all the recommendation into one which would look like this.

[image]

I want to take top 5 recommendation across 3 different tables. FYI, not all the user id can appear in all the tables. Ideally, I want to take TOP 2 from recommendation 1, TOP 3 from recommendation 2. Recommendation 3 is just there so that if there are not enough recommendation from the first two table then recommendation 3 will compensate so at the end I will get 5 results per userID. I don't need to refer to recommendation 3 if I can get 5 recommendation (2 from recommendation 1 and 3 from recommendation 2). when the recommendation 1 has < 2 recommendations per user then I want to get the remaining of the recommendation from recommendation 2. For example, when there is 1 recommendation in Recommendtiaon1 then get 4 recommendation from Recommendation2. Alternatively, if there are 0 recommendation in Recommendation1 then get 5 recommendation from Recommendation2. If Recommednation1 and Recommendation2 doesn't add up to 5 that's when I need to refer to recommendation3. I need to do this in big query SQL. Can you please help?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
with output1 as (
  select *, null as Score, row_number() over win pos
  from Recommendation1 
  where true 
  qualify row_number() over win <= 2
  window win as (partition by UserID order by ProductRecommendation)
), output2 as ( 
  select *, 2 + row_number() over win pos
  from Recommendation2 
  where not (UserID, ProductRecommendation) in (select as struct UserID, ProductRecommendation from output1)  
  qualify row_number() over win <= 5
  window win as (partition by UserID order by Score desc)
), output3 as (
  select *, 7 + row_number() over win pos
  from Recommendation3
  where not (UserID, ProductRecommendation) in (select as struct UserID, ProductRecommendation from output1)  
  and not (UserID, ProductRecommendation) in (select as struct UserID, ProductRecommendation from output2)  
  qualify row_number() over win <= 5
  window win as (partition by UserID order by Score desc)
)
select * except(pos) from (
  select * from output1 union all 
  select * from output2 union all 
  select * from output3
)
where true 
qualify row_number() over win <=5
window win as (partition by UserID order by pos)
# order by UserID, pos
```

if applied to sample data in your question - the output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit unclear.  The following takes 2 rows from the first table for each user, 3 from the second, and additional rows from the third.  The outer query then ensures that there are 5 rows (if available) for each user:

```
select r.*
from ((select userid, recommendation, 1 as which
       from recommendation1
       where 1=1
       qualify row_number() over (partition by userid order by recommendation) <= 2
      ) union all
      (select userid, recommendation, 2 as which
       from recommendation2
       where 1=1
       qualify row_number() over (partition by userid order by score desc) <= 3
      ) union all
      (select userid, recommendation, 3 as which
       from recommendation3
      )
     ) r
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (partition by userid order by which) <= 5;
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It answers most of my problem. However, one of the cases is when the recommendation 1 has < 2 recommendations per user then I want to get the remaining of the recommendation from recommendation 2. For example, when there is 1 recommendation in Recommendtiaon1 then get 4 recommendation from Recommendation2. Alternatively, if there are 0 recommendation in Recommendation1 then get 5 recommendation from Recommendation2.  If Recommednation1 and Recommendation2 doesn't add up to 5 that's when I need to refer to recommendation3. Are you able to incorporate that in your solution?